# Download object from particular AWS mediastore container using boto3

Tags: boto3, mediastore

I don't understand how to specify a container when using boto3 to fetch data from mediastore. I've been trying to use `boto3.client("mediastore-data")`, but in the [docs](http://boto3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/services/mediastore-data.html#MediaStoreData.Client.put_object), it is specified explicitly to

> Do not include the container name in this path.

So when does one specify the container? The code below doesn't connect properly unless I update the `endpointPrefix` of `botocore/data/mediastore-data/2017-09-01/service-2.json` from `data.mediastore` to `<MY_CONTAINER_DATA_ENDPOINT>.data.mediastore`

```
mediastore_data_client = boto3.client(
        "mediastore-data",
        region_name=<MY_REGION_NAME>,
        aws_access_key_id=<MY_AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID>,
        aws_secret_access_key=<MY_AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY>)

obj = mediastore_data_client.get_object(Path=<MY_PATH>)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I also had some difficulties as the documents only describe a part of the constructor's parameters.
Here is what I did to make it work:

```
client = boto3.client(service_name='mediastore-data', region_name='eu-west-1',endpoint_url='https://xxxxxxx.data.mediastore.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com')

response = client2.list_items(Path='mediastorepath')

print response

client.put_object(Body="localpath", Path='mediastorepath')
```

Replace localpath, mediastorepath and xxx with your parameters.
Hope this will help

Comment: Thank you very much! Indeed the piece I was missing was the `endpoint_url` parameter.

Answer (score 0):

The endpoint URL is what defines the container you're trying to get at. Each container has a unique URL endpoint.